# Is there any way to use google translate offline on pc?

Tags: google-chrome, laptop, offline-files, google-translate

I want to use google translate on the laptop without wi-fi. Is there any way to download that, or something like that to use google translate offline?
**like just download that two languages you want to translate to each other**

Answer (score 2):

Google translate for Android supports downloading languages for enabling offline translation.
You could run android in an emulator or virtual machine without an internet connection after the initial setup and languages have been downoaded.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

There are a few commercial translation softwares available that use a local database and don't require an internet connection but software recommendations are off-topic here. Also many of those work better *with* internet for updates, etc.

Google Translate is an online service only.